Why did God take a serious view of Sarah's laughter after ignoring Abraham's?
We read in Gen 17:17( NKJV) , of the immediate reaction of Abraham to God's promise of giving him a progeny :

Then Abraham fell upon his face, and laughed, and said in his heart, Shall a child be born unto him that is an hundred years old? and shall Sarah, that is ninety years old, bear?

We do not see God taking a serious note of Abraham's laughter. But, we see another instance  in Gen 18 : 13-15:

And the Lord said to Abraham, “Why did Sarah laugh, saying, ‘Shall I surely bear a child, since I am old?’  .....
But Sarah denied it, saying, “I did not laugh,” for she was afraid.
And He said, “No, but you did laugh!”.

We see God holding both Abraham  and Sarah responsible for  her laughter. That Sarah was afraid, implies that God's response  was serious.
My question is : Why did God take a serious view of Sarah's laughter after ignoring Abraham's ?
PS: Qs& As on the topic do exist on BHE. I am looking forward to some new perspectives. Please bear with me.

This question is similar to: Why did God react to Abraham and Sarah's laughter concerning the promised son so differently?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The typical answer agrees with Rashi, emphasizing that Abraham responded in joy, while Sarah responded with doubt:

This word ויצחק Onkelos (1st-2nd c.) translates by וחדי which
signifies joy (“and he rejoiced’’) but the similar verb in the case of
Sarah (ותצחק Genesis 18:12) he translates as meaning laughter. From
this you may understand that Abraham had faith and rejoiced, and that
Sarah had no faith and sneered, and that is why God was angry with
Sarah (when she laughed) but was not angry with Abraham.

Since the OP is looking for new perspectives, another idea, possibility related to the above, is that Abraham laughed out loud and questioned in his heart, while Sarah laughed inwardly and expressed her doubt vocally. She also denied laughing, while Abraham did not deny doubting.
A third possibility is that Sarah's laughter may not have been a sin at all, as is often suggested. God simply exposed the fact of her laughter in order to bring her hidden feelings into the open. Sarah had suffered for decades due to the fact of her barrenness, and God tenderly healed this wound by bringing it to light. The story ends happily, with Isaac receiving a name that is a pun on laughter.
